# OCAPI: exclude selected columns

Tags: salesforce, demandware, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I need more columns than less so I thought I could exclude some. It is possible somewhere in body to do it?

POST:

```
https://{url}/s/{name}/dw/shop/v19_10/order_search
```

body:

```
{ 
  "count": 100,
  "db_start_record_": 0,
  "query" : { 
    "filtered_query": {
      "filter": {
        "range_filter": {   
          "field": "last_modified",
          "from": "2024-01-05T09:30:00Z",
          "to": "2024-01-05T10:00:00Z"
        }
      },
      "query" : {
        "match_all_query": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "select" : "(**)",
  "sorts" : [{"field":"creation_date", "sort_order":"asc"}],
  "start" : 0
}
```